# String replace function issue

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I used string replace function in jmeter script and was working fine when I ran the script on the local machine but when the same script was run on the server, it is showing an error.

The function used is : `${__strReplace(${C_Create_Escape},",\\\",)}`
where `create escape` is a regular expression.

On server showing 400 error not passing the string replace function.

**Error:**

```
      "timestamp":1547805846520,"status":400,"error":"Bad Request","exception":"org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException","message":"Could not read document: Unexpected character ('\\' (code 92)): was expecting double-quote to start field name\n
     at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@463eb3f3; line: 1, column: 2804] (through reference chain: 
com.acn.hps.gpp.gibs.dto.FormRequestDTO[\"gibsFormDTO\"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unexpected character ('\\' (code 92)): was expecting double-quote to start field name\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@463eb3f3; line: 1, column: 2804] (through reference chain: com.acn.hps.gpp.gibs.dto.FormRequestDTO[\"gibsFormDTO\"])","path":"/form/createOrEditForm"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [JMeter Documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html):

> If a function parameter contains a comma, then be sure to escape this with "\", otherwise JMeter will treat it as a parameter delimiter.

This restriction has a side-effect: if you need to pass a backslash - you need to escape it with another backslash

So basically if you pass `"a"` to your function you will get `\"a\"` as the result:

[image]

While your server expects it to be escaped with the double slash, to wit `\\"a\\"`

My assumption is that you will need to add some more backslashes in order to be compliant with both JMeter Functions syntax and whatever your server expects. The resulting syntax would be:

```
${__strReplace(${C_Create_Escape},",\\\\\\\",)}
```

[image]

Check out [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) article for more information on JMeter Functions concept.

Comment: Its still showing the same error. I want to replace " with \" . Please suggest the correct syntax